# COPY Command JSONPaths w/ Multiple Credentials

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

Is there a way to provide either multiple credentials or specify something other than an `s3://` path to Redshift `COPY` to load a JSONPaths file?

I have read-only access to a bucket outside of my control, `someone_elses_bucket` in this example.  The documentation for Redshift states that the only 2 options for JSON are 'auto' or  an s3 path:

```
COPY example
FROM 's3://someone_elses_bucket/data' 
CREDENTIALS 'aws_access_key_id=someone_elses_bucket_foo;aws_secret_access_key=someone_elses_bucket_bar' 
DATEFORMAT AS 'auto' 
TRUNCATECOLUMNS 
JSON 's3://my_bucket/redshift_json.json' GZIP;
```

As I do not have access to `someone_elses_bucket` I am forced to put the JSONPaths file in my account.  But I'm getting `S3ServiceException:Access Denied,Status 403,Error AccessDenied` errors.  The file in my bucket is open to the public.  Either I'm doing something wrong or COPY is using my IAM role on the other account to limit my access.  In any event I have no way to supply to a JSONPaths file making it impossible to ingest my formatted data.  `auto` does not work.

Here are my is my bucket policy giving access to my account on 'someone_elses_bucket` (account number replaced for this example):

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Sid": "Example permissions",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal": {
            "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::123456789:user/jerdak"
        },
        "Action": [
            "s3:GetBucketLocation",
            "s3:ListBucket"
        ],
        "Resource": [
            "arn:aws:s3:::my_bucket"
        ]
    }
]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you can't supply more than 1 AWS credentials in one `COPY` command. Whatever credential you supply, Redshift will use it to access both the JSONPaths file and S3 data.

Options that I can think of:

- Do you access `someone_elses_bucket` by an IAM user? If so, provide read access for that IAM user to your bucket and use its credentials in the `COPY` command.
- Run a pre-processing step to copy data from `someone_elses_bucket` to yours, and then `COPY` using your own AWS credentials.

Comment: I clarified my question slightly, I am using credentials provided by 'someone_elses_bucket', additionally I attached the policy I set up that account access to my bucket.  (2) is an option but I'm looking at 2TB of data and a very short turn around.

Comment: still, the options with you remain the same

Comment: With option (1) I'm still getting access denied, unless you mean use a different, more provisioned account?  The policy I appended to my original question is using my read-only IAM account.

Comment: oh, sorry didn't realize that.. along with `"arn:aws:s3:::my_bucket"`, can you also add `"arn:aws:s3:::my_bucket"/*`

Comment: All good, and no luck with that addition.  Option (2) is looking more and more like it's my only path forward.

Comment: i have put Option #1 in production, so i know it works.. i am guessing your bucket policy is not correct..

Comment: oh, i found another problem with your policy.. GetBucketLocation isn't enough. change `GetBucketLocation` => `Get*` and `ListBucket` => `List*`

Comment: if the answer helped, do 'accept' it :) [after checking the last comment above]

Comment: Accepting as technically (2) was correct but none of the steps in the comments resulted in a successful (1),.